# Emacs does not auto restart after reboot?

Tags: homebrew, emacs, symlink, restart

I install Emacs via Homebrew and create a symbolic link:

/Applications/Emacs.app -> /usr/local/Cellar/emacs/24.3/Emacs.app

What does not seem to work properly is that after restarting, other applications previously open will automatically restart but Emacs does not.  Any ideas?